# Getting only the folder path by browse button

Tags: c++, file, filepath

I am getting a complete **path of a file** by browsing through the folder and selecting a file after i click **browse button.**

But i want to get **path upto the folder only** by browsing.

I did the following for the file path

```
                 Stream^ myStream;  
                 OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

                 openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
                 //openFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                 openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
                 openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

                 if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
                 {
                     if ( (myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr )
                     {                               

                         String^ p1 = openFileDialog1->FileName; 


                         MessageBox ::Show (p1);

                         myStream->Close();
                     }
```

Comment: Should you be using instead a FolderBrowserDialog?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx

Comment: oh! i ddn't know about it. Will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting folder paths rather than file names, use [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx)